# loading and naming multiple files into R

Tags: r, load

I have over 1000 data sets I would like to load into R and name each one separately as they are loaded in. I found that to load them I can use the commands:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")

for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i]))
```

but how would I name each file as it is loaded so I can easily call each one later on?

Comment: How do you want to name them? This code will create `data.frame` with the same name as the file.

Comment: Note that if you ever want to loop over them, you're better off using `x = lapply(temp, read.csv); names(x) = temp`. If you want to access them randomly then the above is fine.

Comment: All my file names have numbers in them. For example the years 1988 to 2006 so when I go to call them it just says "unexpected constant" and doesn't show me the data. I'd like to call them 1august2006 or something of that form changing for each file.

Comment: If you've created an object named "1august2006" using `assign`, you'll have to get it with `get("1august2006")`. If it's in a list as per Simon's excellent suggestion, access it via `x[["1august2006"]]` (rather than `x$1august2006`).

Comment: ah okay got it! Thanks guys that works. Thanks for the suggestion Simon and the clarification regetz. I'm new to R so can't catch onto everything right away.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is better to get your data.frame aggregated in a list.
Using `sapply` to loop you get a named list with file names.

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
named.list <- sapply(temp, read.csv)
```

**EDIT**

To avoid the case of data frames with the same number of columns, you need to set `simplify=FALSE`

```
named.list <- sapply(temp, read.csv,simplify=FALSE)
```

Comment: I think you're going to want to include `simplify=FALSE` with sapply here. And presumably assign the result to something in order to use it in subsequent statements.

Comment: The default for simplify is TRUE as of R 2.15.2 and all previous versions I can recall. Hence the 's' in `sapply`, no? If all of the read-in data frames have the same number of columns, i.e. all are lists of equal length, the result will be a "simplified" matrix of lists rather than a list of data frames.

Comment: @regetz why do you want I use `simplify=FALSE`? did you test this code to see its output ? here you get the same output with simplify TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: Try `write.csv(head(iris), a<-tempfile()); write.csv(tail(iris), b<-tempfile()); sapply(c(a,b), read.csv)`. I suspect your test included at least two input tables with differing numbers of columns? Even if I knew this to be true of the OP's data, which I don't, I would avoid code that implicitly relies on this.

Comment: @regetz you're right. I see my error. included at least two input tables with differing numbers of columns. thanks. I edited my answer.

Comment: @agstudy. I often find `lapply` is simpler than `sapply(..., simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: @mnel yes mee too. but I use `sapply` here for its `USE.NAMES = TRUE` argument.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a list of data.frame names, similar to your list of file names. 
Then everything else is almost the same, except for a small change in your `assign` statement

```
  temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")

  # just an example
  dataNames <- paste0(c("dataSource_", 1:length(temp)))

  # then everything else is almost the same
  for (i in 1:length(temp)) 
      assign(dataNames[i], read.csv(temp[i]))
```