# Function to read in multiple delimited text files

Tags: r, function, csv

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15056759/2416535), I have created a function that should read in all the text datasets in a directory:

```
read.delims = function(dir, sep = "\t"){

  # Make a list of all data frames in the "data" folder
  list.data = list.files(dir, pattern = "*.(txt|TXT|csv|CSV)")

  # Read them in
  for (i in 1:length(list.data)) {
    assign(list.data[i],
           read.delim(paste(dir, list.data[i], sep = "/"),
                      sep = sep))
  }

}
```

However, even though there are .txt and .csv files in the specified directory, no R objects get created (I'm guessing this happens because I'm using the `read.delim` within a function). How to correct this?

Comment: Your function does not have a return value. Try adding `return(list.data)` in the end.

Comment: Adding `return(list.data)` prints out the list, but does not create any data frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the parameter `envir` in your assignment, like this :

```
read.delims = function(dir, sep = "\t"){

  # Make a list of all data frames in the "data" folder
  list.data = list.files(dir, pattern = "*.(txt|TXT|csv|CSV)")

  # Read them in
  for (i in 1:length(list.data)) {
    assign(list.data[i],
           read.delim(paste(dir, list.data[i], sep = "/"),
                      sep = sep),
          envir=.GlobalEnv)
  }
}
```

Doing this, your object will be created in the global environment and not just in the function environment

Comment: Exactly what I wanted (notwithstanding the validity of @Simon 's comment).

Comment: great ! I'm happy if I helped you :-)

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, it is necessary to `return()` a value after assigning. I don't really see the point in using `assign()` though, so here it is with a simple for-loop, assuming you want your output to be a list of data frames.

Note that I changed the reading function to `read.table()` for personal convenience. You might want to adjust that.

```
read.delims <- function(dir, sep = "\t"){

  # Make a list of all data frames in the "data" folder
  list.data <- list.files(dir, pattern = "*.(txt|TXT|csv|CSV)")
  list.out <- as.list(1:length(list.data))

  # Read them in
  for (i in 1:length(list.data)) {
    list.out[[i]] <- read.table(paste(dir, list.data[i], sep = "/"), sep = sep)
  }
  return(list.out)
}
```

Maybe you should also add a `$` to your regular expression.

Cheers.

Comment: I feel like we're getting somewhere! Now the function prints out the data frames (i.e., contents of the files). But it still does not create any objects in my workspace. Ideally, it should create a group of objects with names identical to the names of files they were created out of (without the file extension). Could it break down the list and create separate data frames out of it? Or must this be a second step outside the function?

Comment: Okay, I now finally get what you are trying to achieve. You want to create one object for each file... This I consider bad practice actually because you clutter the workspace with objects this way and it's easy to lose track of them. It's better to save them into a list, keeping them all inside one single object. The function above does exactly that. Just assign the output to an object, e.g., `datasets <- read.delims(...)` and you will have a list that contains all the datasets. Each dataset can be accessed by, e.g., `datasets[[1]]` for the first dataset.

Comment: Having them all in a list is not only "better practice", but can also be much more convenient. For example, it's easy to bind them together (if they share the same format) using `do.call(rbind, ...)` or to carry out a common tast in all datasets using `lapply()`. EDIT: If you really want separate objects, then have a look at CathG's suggestion below. It fixes your `assign()` call, and you get separate objects with that.

Comment: Duly noted. This function is meant to load datasets already prepared for subsequent analyses. Since every object created in this way has its own premeditated role in the process, the risk of unnecessary clutter is eliminated. However, I will keep your comment in mind (as well as the useful remark about `lapply` etc.)